# Как справиться с ошибкой функии protected??Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, framework

вообщем осваиваю laravel. Пытаюсь сделать форму регистрации на блог, при обьявлении функции вылетает такая ошибка :

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)"

вот сам код :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller

{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    /**
    * @param Request $request
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
    */

    public function register( Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю, что ошибка из-за того, что я не обьявил класс Request, но я также не могу его импортировать по неизвестным мне причинам. вставлял через app/library/request в controller, ошибка все равно выходит. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: **Сообщение об ошибке надо приводить полностью!** Ну неужели трудно догадаться что читатели не имеют представления, на какой именно оператор protected ругается РНР?

Comment: А если сообщение об ошибке ещё и **прочитать**, и посмотреть рядом со строкой, на которую оно указывает, то и исправить можно будет самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение `Unexpected {smth}` указывает на то, что произошло что-то неожиданное. В данном случае, в конце функции `register` ожидается фигурная скобка, у вас ее нет, поэтому отображается ошибка о неожиданном слове `protected`.

Решение: поставить закрывающую фигурную скобку в конце функции `register`.

Comment: верно, опередил)